# grep from file doesn't write result to an output file

Tags: bash, grep

I'm trying to grep strings from file2.csv using existing strings from file1.csv and write matched lines to result.csv file. A have a following bash script:

```
cat file1.csv | while read line; do
    grep $line ./file2.csv > result.csv
done
```

But afterall the result.csv is always empty. When I do manual grep from file2.csv everything works fine. What I do wrong?

file1.csv:

```
15098662745072
15098662745508
```

file2.csv:

```
";"0";"15098662745072";"4590";"4590";"
";"0";"15098662745508";"6400";"6400";"
";"0";"15098662745515";"6110";"6110";"
";"0";"15098662745812";"7970";"7970";"
```

expected result (result.csv):

```
";"0";"15098662745072";"4590";"4590";"
";"0";"15098662745508";"6400";"6400";"
```

Comment: Please provide small examples of file1.csv and file2.csv and your expected result.

Comment: @svante pls see the updated post with file examples

Comment: @dogbane's solutions(s) works on my system. Check your spelling/linefeeds/file permissions.

Comment: @svante i've just created duplicates of file1 and file2 and everything works fine now. but i have no idea why this doesn't work with my old files..

Comment: Most likely you have `\r\n` at the end of `file1.csv` (you can check using `od -bc < file1.csv`)

Comment: @dogbane finally i have found out a cause of the problem: file1.csv has empty line in the end. after removing it everything runs perfect. appreciate your help.

Comment: @anubhava yes, that was the cause of the problem. thx!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`>` keeps overwriting the file. Use `>>` to append to it.

Instead of using a loop, you can simply use the `-f` option in `grep` to make `grep` read patterns from the file.

```
grep -f file1.csv file2.csv > result.csv
```

If you have to use a loop, use the following approach:

```
while read line; do
    grep "$line" ./file2.csv
done < file1.csv > result.csv
```

Comment: If you have to use a bash loop always add `IFS=` and use `read -r` unless you have a specific functionality you require out of not using them.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using awk for this, not grep, because:

a) grep does not by default look for strings, it looks for regular expressions. You need to use `fgrep` or `grep -F` or `awk` instead of `grep` to search for strings.

b) You really only want to match the numbers from file1.csv when they appear as a full specific field in file2.csv, not wherever they occur on the line.

```
awk -F'";"' 'NR==FNR{a[$0];next} $3 in a' file1.csv file2.csv > result.csv
```